# Best Practice for Creating A - Z Index using Linq in Asp.net

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq

I wanted to created an A - Z index that pulls information from a SQL database via linq and was wondering what would be the best approach in regards to creating something very close where you have at the top A | B.....| Z and as a user clicks on a letter it is populated.

What I have so far is:

```
@{ 
  var career = new career_servicesEntities(); 
  var result = (from item in career.JobLists orderby item.Name ascending select item); 

  foreach (var res in result) 
  { 
      <div> <ul> <li><a href="@res.Link">@res.Name</a></li> </ul> </div>
  }
 }
```

What I'm trying to recreate is something like this page:

- http://www.usi.edu/careersv/jobsearch.asp

Comment: What have you got so far? Can you be more specific?

Comment: I have created the database and Im just looking for the best approach to starting this using linq

Comment: I updated the question with the information posted by the OP throughout this thread and voted to reopen. I've already spent a bunch of time on this question and written several samples for it so i'm invested now :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are talking about a directory, then you would have your letters action an event or set a variable that you can use in your linq.

```
var myData = entity.Where(o=>o.colName.StartsWith(letter)).OrderBy(o=>o.colName);
```

Maybe when they click on 'C' it does ?letter=C in querystring

You can then pick it out and use it as part of my above query, simplified slightly (Look up general usage of EF to create context etc)

Comment: Yes im doing something pretty much like a directory. As close as possible to this: http://www.usi.edu/careersv/jobsearch.asp

Comment: This is where I a mso far: 
@{
    var career = new career_servicesEntities();
    var result = (from item in career.JobLists                  
                  orderby item.Name ascending 
                  select item);

 foreach (var res in result)
 {
    <div>
      <ul>
          <li><a href="@res.Link">@res.Name</a></li>
       </ul>
    </div>
 }
}

Answer (score 0):

This method will return a snippet of html markup with an A-Z roulette of links in it. If there are no jobs under the current letter then it will just show the letter without a link. I think you can modify this to your MVC project quite easily.

```
private string GetAlphaRouletteLinksHtmlMarkup()
{
    var JobList = new List<String>() {
        "AccessibleEmployment",
        "accessIndiana",
        "AccountingNet",
        "Alldiversity.com",
        "American Chemical Society",
        "America's Job Bank",
        "Art Careers",
        "Asian MBA",
        "Back Door Jobs",
        "Career Search",
        "Careerbliss",
        "Careerbuilder",
        "CareerJet",
        "CareerMagazine",
        "CareerMosaic",
        "CareerOverview",
        "Careers 2005",
        "City of Evansville jobs",
        "College Recruiter",
        "CollegeGrad.com",
        "ComputerJobs",
        "Conservation Job Board",
        "Cuyahoga County Public Library",
        "Dentist Jobs Help",
        "EMPLOYMENTCROSSING",
        "Evansville Courier & Press Classifieds",
        "Exam2Jobs",
        "Experience.com",
        "Federal Government Jobs",
        "Flipdog",
        "FPSelectJobs",
        "hotjobs",
        "Hound",
        "Idealist",
        "Indeed",
        "Indiana Health Careers",
        "Indiana Job Central",
        "Indiana Youth Institute",
        "IndianaCAREERConnect",
        "Inside Jobs",
        "Internships",
        "Jackson County Industrial Development Corporation",
        "Jamminjobs",
        "Job Application Center",
        "Job Search USA",
        "Job Seeker's Bookmarks",
        "Job-Applications",
        "JobCo",
        "Jobs in Indianapolis Web site",
        "JobScribble",
        "Journal of Young Investors",
        "Learn More Indiana",
        "Louisville, KY jobs",
        "Mediapost",
        "NBMBAA",
        "News-Line Communications",
        "On-Line Career Center",
        "Online Recruiters Directory",
        "PeaceCorps",
        "Quintessential Careers",
        "Riley Guide",
        "RiseSmart",
        "SallieMae True Careers",
        "ScienceJobs.com",
        "Simply Hired",
        "SmartBrief",
        "Snagajob.com",
        "State government job opportunities",
        "Student Employment Opportunities",
        "Teacher Jobs Help",
        "The Ladders Career Advice",
        "U. S. Department of State",
        "USAJOBS",
        "wetfeet",
        "WomensJobSearch",
        "Work In Sports",
        "WorkplaceDiversity"
    };

    var letters = from alpha in Enumerable.Range('A', 'Z' - 'A' + 1).Select(c => c.ToString())
                  let firstLetters = (from job in JobList
                                      orderby job
                                      group job by job[0].ToString().ToUpper() into firstLetters
                                      select firstLetters.Key)
                  select new
                  {
                      Letter = alpha,
                      IsLink = firstLetters.Contains(alpha)
                  };

    StringBuilder outputHtml = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (var item in letters)
    {
        if (item.IsLink)
        {
            // add html
            outputHtml.AppendFormat("<a href=\"#roulette{0}\">{1}</a> | ", item.Letter, item.Letter);
        }
        else
        {
            // no html
            outputHtml.Append(item.Letter);
            outputHtml.Append(" | ");
        }
    }

    return outputHtml.ToString().TrimEnd(" | ".ToCharArray());
}
```

All thats left for you to do is merge this code in and also keep your existing attempt which outputs the list of individual jobs.

Update - I improved by moving more of it into a single LINQ statement by pushing the first letters into a sub-select. Code posted is the updated version without the massive `JobList` declaration:

Update 2 - I replaced the string split with some more LINQ which generates the uppercase alphabet in this snippet and merged the updates together.